# multi ng -repeat and remove rows in angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm new to AngularJs and I'm stuck in multi ng-repeat.
[image]

HTML CODE

```
<table class="table table-bordered tdPaddingNull verTop">
                      <thead>
                        <tr>
                          <th width="200px">Product Details </th>
                          <th width="250px">Current Availability</th>
                          <th width="200px">Batch </th>                                                                          
                          <th>Quantity</th>                                                     
                          <th>Rate INR </th>                                                     
                          <th>Amt. INR</th>                                                     
                          <th>Converted Amount</th>                                                     
                        </tr>
                      </thead>

                      <tbody>
                        <tr ng-repeat="(i,product) in listproducts track by $index">
                          <td style="padding: 7px;"> 
                                <input auto-complete ui-items="prductdetail" ng-model="formData.product_name[i]" class="form-control form-white" my-id="{{i}}"/>
                                <input id="product_id{{i}}" placeholder="productid"  type="hidden" value="" ng-model="formData.product_id[i]" my-id="{{i}}"/>

                                <a ng-click="addProductBatch()" title="Add Another Batch Quantity" style="float:right;"><i class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i> ADD BATCH </a>
                          </td> 
                          <td class="line-item-column item-currentavail transferorder-lineitem">
                             <div class="row text-muted font-sm">
                              <div class="col-md-6">
                              Source Stock
                            </div>
                            <div class="separationline col-md-6">
                              Destination Stock
                            </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row font-xs">
                              <div class="col-md-6">
                                0.00 Units
                              </div>
                              <div class="separationline col-md-6">
                                0.00 Units
                              </div>
                            </div>
                           </td>
                          <td style="padding: 7px;"> 
                               <div style="display:inline-block;width:100%;" ng-repeat="addBatch in listAddbatches">
                                    <select  class="form-control form-white  selectNor" ng-model="formData.batch_id[i]" ng-change="changedBatchValue(formData.batch_id)" style="margin-bottom: 5px;width: 88%;float: left;">
                                         <option value="">Select Batch</option>
                                         <option value="{{blist.batch_id}}" ng-repeat="blist in batchList">{{blist.batch_number}}</option>
                                     </select> 
                                     <a class="inputTabel1" ng-click="removeBatch($index)" title="Remove Batch"  style="float:left;margin-left: 4px;"> <i class="fa fa-times-circle-o" aria-hidden="true" ></i>
                                     </a>
                                </div>                                   
                          </td>                              

                          <td style="padding: 7px;"> 
                              <input class="form-control form-white"  type="text" value="" ng-model="formData.product_count[i]" ng-repeat="addBatch in listAddbatches"  style="margin-bottom: 5px;"/>
                          </td> 
                          <td style="padding: 7px;"> 
                                <input class="form-control form-white "  placeholder="Selling Price"  type="text" value="0.00" ng-model="formData.sel_inr_rate[i]">
                          </td>
                          <td> 
                                <input class="form-control form-white form-Tabel"  placeholder="Amount in INR"  type="text" value="0.00" ng-model="formData.sel_inr_amount[i]" readonly />
                          </td>
                          <td class="Amount  "> 
                                <input class="form-control form-white form-Tabel"  placeholder=""  type="text" value="0.00" ng-model="formData.exc_total_amount[i]" readonly />
                                <button class="inputTabel" ng-click="removeProduct($index)"> <i class="fa fa-times-circle-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                </button>
                          </td>  
                        </tr>
                      </tbody>
                    </table>
```

ANGULAR CODE

```
/****************ADD ANOTHER BATCH QUANTITY**************/
    $scope.addAnotherProduct = function(listproducts,$event) {
        newItemNo = $scope.listproducts.length+1;
        $scope.listproducts.push({'batch_id[newItemNo]':'','product_count[newItemNo]':''});
      };
    $scope.removeProduct = function(index) {
        /*var lastItem = $scope.listproducts.length-1;
        $scope.listproducts.splice(lastItem);
        $scope.listAddbatches = '';*/
         $scope.listproducts.splice(index,1);
      };
      $scope.removeBatch = function(index) {
        /*var lastItem = $scope.listAddbatches.length-1;
        $scope.listAddbatches.splice(lastItem);
        $scope.listAddbatches = '';*/
         $scope.listAddbatches.splice(index,1);
      };
    $scope.addProductBatch = function() {
        var newItemNo = $scope.listAddbatches.length+1;
        $scope.listAddbatches.push({'id':'batch'+newItemNo});
      };
```

Here when I click `ADD ANOTHER PRODUCT` it should create an entire row in the table without the columns of Batch and Quantity, but now it's appearing as it in before row created.

Then when I click `ADD BATCH` it should create under the table column Batch and Quantity of the corresponding row, but now it's adding in all the rows and when I remove added batch, it should remove the corresponding batch, but now it's removing the last added batch.

The same happens when I remove added product (Entire Row), it should remove the corresponding row of the product but now it's removing lastly added Product row.

How can I fix all the aforementioned issues?

Please help me

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple issues with your approach:

1) You are using a global array `listAddbatches` but you want to add the batches by product, so why shouldn't you use `product.listAddbatches` array?

2) When [using `track by $index` you will not able to delete correct element from array or object since `compiler` directive is not re-compiling the element when its data attribute changes](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/7119).

3) Using array length to generate id like `var newItemNo = $scope.listAddbatches.length + 1;` is not a good idea since the array length could change (when removing items) in a way that you will have the same ids for different elements.

4) This line is very strange `{'batch_id[newItemNo]':'','product_count[newItemNo]':''}`, since you are calculating `newItemNo`, but this is a simple string `'batch_id[newItemNo]'`. Why do you need this?

5) Do not recommend to use `$index` to remove items, since it could point to some other element in case of filtering.

Your code could like this (simplified version), hope this helps:

```js
angular.module('plunker', [])
.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
      $scope.listproducts = [];

      $scope.addAnotherProduct = function(listproducts) {
        listproducts.push( {
            listAddbatches: []
        });
      };

      $scope.removeProduct = function(product) {
         var index = $scope.listproducts.indexOf(product); 
         if (index >= 0)
            $scope.listproducts.splice(index, 1);
      };

      $scope.removeBatch = function(product, batch) {
         var index = product.listAddbatches.indexOf(batch); 
         if (index >= 0)
           product.listAddbatches.splice(index, 1);
      };

      $scope.addProductBatch = function(product) {
        product.listAddbatches.push({ });
      }; 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.6.4/angular.js" ></script>
<html ng-app="plunker">
  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  
<table class="table table-bordered tdPaddingNull verTop">
                      <thead>
                        <tr>
                          <th width="200px">Product Details </th>
                          <th width="250px">Current Availability</th>
                          <th width="200px">Batch </th>                                                                          
                          <th>Quantity</th>                                                     
                          <th>Rate INR </th>                                                     
                          <th>Amt. INR</th>                                                     
                          <th>Converted Amount</th>                                                     
                        </tr>
                      </thead>

                      <tbody>
                        <tr ng-repeat="(i, product) in listproducts">
                          <td style="padding: 7px;"> 
                                <input auto-complete ui-items="prductdetail" ng-model="formData.product_name[i]" class="form-control form-white" my-id="{{i}}"/>
                                <input id="product_id{{i}}" placeholder="productid"  type="hidden" value="" ng-model="formData.product_id[i]" my-id="{{i}}"/>

                                <a ng-click="addProductBatch(product)" title="Add Another Batch Quantity" style="float:right;"><i class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i> ADD BATCH </a>
                          </td> 
                          <td class="line-item-column item-currentavail transferorder-lineitem">
                             <div class="row text-muted font-sm">
                              <div class="col-md-6">
                              Source Stock
                            </div>
                            <div class="separationline col-md-6">
                              Destination Stock
                            </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row font-xs">
                              <div class="col-md-6">
                                0.00 Units
                              </div>
                              <div class="separationline col-md-6">
                                0.00 Units
                              </div>
                            </div>
                           </td>
                          <td style="padding: 7px;"> 
                               <div style="display:inline-block;width:100%;" ng-repeat="addBatch in product.listAddbatches">
                                    <select  class="form-control form-white  selectNor" ng-model="formData.batch_id[i]" ng-change="changedBatchValue(formData.batch_id)" style="margin-bottom: 5px;width: 88%;float: left;">
                                         <option value="">Select Batch</option>
                                         <option value="{{blist.batch_id}}" ng-repeat="blist in batchList">{{blist.batch_number}}</option>
                                     </select> 
                                     <a class="inputTabel1" ng-click="removeBatch(product, addBatch)" title="Remove Batch"  style="float:left;margin-left: 4px;"> <i class="fa fa-times-circle-o" aria-hidden="true" ></i>
                                     </a>
                                </div>                                   
                          </td>                              

                          <td style="padding: 7px;"> 
                              <input class="form-control form-white"  type="text" value="" ng-model="formData.product_count[i]" ng-repeat="addBatch in product.listAddbatches"  style="margin-bottom: 5px;"/>
                          </td> 
                          <td style="padding: 7px;"> 
                                <input class="form-control form-white "  placeholder="Selling Price"  type="text" value="0.00" ng-model="formData.sel_inr_rate[i]">
                          </td>
                          <td> 
                                <input class="form-control form-white form-Tabel"  placeholder="Amount in INR"  type="text" value="0.00" ng-model="formData.sel_inr_amount[i]" readonly />
                          </td>
                          <td class="Amount  "> 
                                <input class="form-control form-white form-Tabel"  placeholder=""  type="text" value="0.00" ng-model="formData.exc_total_amount[i]" readonly />
                                <button class="inputTabel" ng-click="removeProduct(product)"> <i class="fa fa-times-circle-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                </button>
                          </td>  
                        </tr>
                      </tbody>
                    </table>
                    
                    
                    
            <button ng-click="addAnotherProduct(listproducts)">Add Another Product</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. yes I know there is multiple issues cause beginner of Angular. the code which you answered working here, same I copy and paste to my project. it working but removing batch not work properly, still it remove last Batch added. But here its working properly. Please help me

Comment: @Gopalakrishnan try removing all the occurrences of `track by $index` in the html view just to diagnose the problem and see if this helps. Possibly you can make a jsfiddle which  can illustrate the issue you are experiencing?

Comment: no $index in my html page. but it still removing last elements of batch

Comment: Can you please attach a working example that will illustrate the problem?

Comment: I just copy your code and paste into my code @stanislav

Comment: when i separate that code add batch and add product only it works absolutely working fine. but when i place into my page. it wont work:(

Comment: So looks like it is related to your sources. Try to check if this methods are not overridden  somewhere, also try to debug and see what methods are called and with what arguments.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147187/discussion-between-gopalakrishnan-and-stanislav-kvitash).